# int obtained from editText is not displayed

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, int, sharedpreferences

I am doing a saving system with sharedPreferences, the problem is that when I run the application it seems that if the String is saved but when converting it to int later it returns null values or 0...
the edit text only receives numbers, and what I try is to obtain its value as a string and then convert it to int, since I want to use that value in another activity

```
package com.example.ml_prototipe_a;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText inputLimiter;
private TextView mostrarLimite;
public String limiterStr;
public int limiterInt;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mostrarLimite = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.MostrarAciertos);
    inputLimiter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.InLimAciertos);
    limiterStr = inputLimiter.getText().toString().trim();

    Button btnRecNotas = findViewById(R.id.recNotasBtn);
    Button btnGuardarLim = findViewById(R.id.GuardarLimite);
    btnRecNotas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intRecNotas = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainRecNotas.class);
            startActivityForResult(intRecNotas, 0);
        }
    });
    btnGuardarLim.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });
}
public void Cargar(View view){
    SharedPreferences limitPrefs= getBaseContext().getSharedPreferences("limitData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String recovaStr = limitPrefs.getString("numbreLimiter", "");
    if(!"".equals(recovaStr)) {
        limiterInt = Integer.parseInt(recovaStr);
        mostrarLimite.setText("aciertos: " + limiterInt);
        System.out.println(limiterInt);
    }
}

public void Guardar(View view){
if(mostrarLimite!=null) {
    SharedPreferences limitPrefs = getBaseContext().getSharedPreferences("limitData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editer = limitPrefs.edit();
    editer.putString("numberLimiter", limiterStr);
    editer.apply();
  }
 }
}
```

---

NEW CODE!!!!********************************

```
package com.example.ml_prototipe_a;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText inputLimiter;
private TextView mostrarLimite;
public String limiterStr;
public int limiterInt;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mostrarLimite = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MostrarAciertos);
    inputLimiter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.InLimAciertos);

    Button btnRecNotas = findViewById(R.id.recNotasBtn);
    Button btnGuardarLim = findViewById(R.id.GuardarLimite);
    Button btnCargarLimTEMP = findViewById(R.id.cargarTemp);
    btnRecNotas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intRecNotas = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainRecNotas.class);
            startActivityForResult(intRecNotas, 0);
        }
    });
    btnGuardarLim.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Guardar();
        }
    });
    btnCargarLimTEMP.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Cargar();
        }
    });
}

private void Cargar() {
    SharedPreferences limitPrefs = getBaseContext().getSharedPreferences("limitData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String recovaStr = limitPrefs.getString("numbreLimiter", "");
    try {
        limiterInt = Integer.parseInt(recovaStr);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        System.out.println("Could not parse " + nfe);
    }
    mostrarLimite.setText("aciertos: " + limiterInt);
    System.out.println(limiterInt);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Limite de aciertos: " + limiterInt, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private void Guardar() {
    if (mostrarLimite != null) {
        SharedPreferences limitPrefs = getBaseContext().getSharedPreferences("limitData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editer = limitPrefs.edit();
        editer.putString("numberLimiter", limiterStr);
        editer.apply();
        limiterStr = inputLimiter.getText().toString().trim();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Limite de aciertos actualizado: " + limiterStr, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        System.out.println(limiterStr);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You never update `limiterStr` before saving it to `SharedPreferences`, so it always has the original value. Move the `limiterStr = inputLimiter.getText().toString().trim();` line from `onCreate()` – since it's not really needed there – to the `Guardar()` method, before the `editer.putString()` call.

Comment: I have tried as you mentioned, and it always ends up returning 0, it looks more or less like this ... (in my question is the new code

Comment: I already solved the error, when saving the string I called it "numberLimiter" and when I called it I did it as "numbreLimiter" ... anyway without the solution you gave it wouldn't have worked either, thanks!